# how to delete vertices remaining inside

Tags: vertices, mirror

[image]I had created something using mirror modifier. Some parts are completely separate but the parts closer to center are partially separate, with some portions remaining within each other. How can I delete the vertices that are inside?
Second question: also please tell me how to smooth that part from outside which is like a dent right now, where two symmetrical parts join each other but were not entirely separated.

In the picture attached, you see the intersecting part. a lot of faces remain inside. I want to eliminate them and then make the outer face smooth

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe simply use the *Bisect* option on the mirror axis?

Without the option:

[image]

With the option:

[image]

Comment: it works thanks. and how to smooth out the dented portion in the middle do you know? (your picture also has it - the dent in the middle)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you mean make it less sharper you can select the edge and bevel (Ctrl B)? Or please share your file and also elaborate what you mean by smooth?

Comment: I already shared my image. Look at your second image. You see the long vertical dent in the middle? How to make it disappear and make that level with the rest of the shape?

Comment: If you want to dissolve the central edge, select and Ctrl X?